# How to remove unique character based on the same index via regex

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

while learning through SO's one of the question, where using regex to extract values.

I am wondering how we can implement a regex to remove all the characters if the are same in every row and matching the same index position.

### Below is the DataFrame:

```
print(df)
   column1
0  [b,e,c]
1  [e,a,c]
2  [a,b,c]
```

regex :

```
 df.column1.str.extract(r'(\w,\w)')

 print(df)
  column1
0     b,e
1     e,a
2     a,b
```

In the above regex it extract the characters needed but i want to preserve `[]` this as well.

Comment: Are there strings in `column1`? Do you actually have `'[b,e,c]'` there?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, yes these are all strings.

Comment: If there are strings in `column1`, try `df['column1'].str.replace(r'\[(\w,\w).*', r'[\1]', regex=True)`

Comment: it produced an error.. `sre_constants.error: unterminated character set at position 0`

Comment: No, it works well, you must have left out the escape before `[`

Comment: Ok, another approach: `'[' + df['column1'].str.extract(r'(\w,\w)') + ']'`

Comment: Yes, it works well but i need to understand , how it makes sure the same position.

Comment: The solutions are posted below. If you need to adjust the solutions, please post the exact pattern requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
df['column2'] = df['column1'].str.replace(r'(?s).*?\[(\w,\w).*', r'[\1]', regex=True)
df['column2'] = '[' + df['column1'].str.extract(r'(\w,\w)') + ']'
```

In the `.str.replace` approach, the `(?s).*?\[(\w,\w).*` matches any zero or more chars as few as possible, then a `[`, then captures a word char + comma + a word char into Group 1 (`\1`) and then the rest of the string and replaces the match with `[` + Group 1 value + `]`.

In the second approach, `[` and `]` are added to the result of the extraction, this solution is best for your toy examples here.

Here is a Pandas test:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'column1':['[b,e,c]']})
>>> df['column1'].str.replace(r'(?s).*?\[(\w,\w).*', r'[\1]', regex=True)
0    [b,e]
Name: column1, dtype: object

>>> '[' + df['column1'].str.extract(r'(\w,\w)') + ']'
       0
0  [b,e]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer  as this satisfies the sample requirement but i need if there could be a future proof solution ensuring if the character is same at the same index position

Comment: @kulfi You need to provide exact specs. Otherwise, `df['column1'].str.replace(r'(?s).*?\[(\w,\w).*', r'[\1]', regex=True)` might suffice. The second solution adding `[` and `]` around extracted values seems the simplest.